# .map() issue in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcna-jJtAXk&t=5s) tutorial. In this regard I have below code in React.js

```
render () {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
        <Container>
            <Button
                color = "dark"
                style = { { marginBottom: '2rem' } }
                onClick = { () => {
                    const name = prompt( 'Enter Item' ); 
                    if(name) {
                        this.setState( state => ( {
                            items: [...state.items, { id: uuid(), name }]
                        } ));
                    }
                } }
            >Add Item</Button>
            <ListGroup>
                <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
                    { 
                        items.map(({id, name}) => {
                            <CSSTransition key = { id } timeout = { 500 } classNames = "fade" >
                                <ListGroupItem>
                                    { name }
                                </ListGroupItem>
                            </CSSTransition>
                        })
                    }
                </TransitionGroup>
            </ListGroup>                        
        </Container>
    ); 
}
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

Why I am getting this error ? The issue is inside `.map()`. I tried several ways but could not find the solution.

***UPDATE***

I am not getting any error if I use below code

```
<ListGroup>
    <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
        { 

        }
    </TransitionGroup>
</ListGroup>
```

Comment: Post your TransitionGroup component code

Comment: try `return <CSSTransition`

Comment: I think you forgot to returnthe JSX element in map's callback

Comment: can you please post `CSSTransition` and `ListGroupItem` component's code

Comment: Thanks @JigarShah. This is a package which I installed. I `import` them like below `import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';`. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing was getting returned in the map. Update your code to following and it will work.

```
<ListGroup>
   <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
      { 
        items.map(({id, name}) => {
         return (<CSSTransition key = { id } timeout = { 500 } classNames = "fade" >
              <ListGroupItem>
                 { name }
              </ListGroupItem>
         </CSSTransition>)
         })
      }
   </TransitionGroup>
</ListGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Gupta. I tried your solution but it is not working. I updated the `Question`, I think that will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

You forget the return keyword inside block statement

```
<ListGroup>
   <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
     { 
       items.map(({id, name}) => {
          return <CSSTransition key = { id } timeout = { 500 } classNames = "fade" >
               <ListGroupItem>
                 { name }
               </ListGroupItem>
             </CSSTransition>
        })
     }
   </TransitionGroup>
</ListGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping a `div` or `span` around and inside your `CSSTransition`.

```
<ListGroup>
  <TransitionGroup className="shopping-list">
    { items.map(({id, name}) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <CSSTransition key = { id } timeout = { 500 } classNames = "fade" >
            <div>
              <ListGroupItem>
                { name }
              </ListGroupItem>
            </div>
          </CSSTransition>
        </div>
    ))}
  </TransitionGroup>
</ListGroup>
```

Also there's a huge difference between `react-transition-group` version 1 and version 2. Make sure to use the appropriate version (v1 is much easier to work with).

Take a look at this working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2pyrr8l33n

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: true,
    text: ["Wow", "this", "works!"]
  };

  handleClick = () =>
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isVisible: !this.state.isVisible
    }));

  render = () => (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>
        <CSSTransition
          in={this.state.isVisible}
          timeout={300}
          classNames="messagein"
          unmountOnExit
        >
          <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }} className="messageout">
            {this.state.text.map(text => <p key={text}>{text}</p>)}
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
      <button
        className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
      >
        {this.state.isVisible ? "Hide" : "Show"} Text
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matt charlotta. Your solution is not working. How can I check `items` array ?

Comment: Please fork the codesandbox and replace my code with yours (if you need to add a module dependency, click the "Add Dependency" button on the bottom left, type in the module name in the search box, and double click to install it). This will help me narrow down your issue of why it's not working.